# Can't get CSS alignment of an image to work

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am working on this page:

http://g33ktalk.com/etsy-a-deep-dive-into-monitoring-with-skyline/

and you see how towards the bottom, the image to subscribe doesn't have padding and touches the divs.

I tried to do something like this:

```
#gform_submit_button_8
{
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

But that had no effect. I also tried to add padding to the class `gform_footer` but it also had no effect.  Would anyone know how to add padding to the left side of that image?

EDIT:

This is the larger HTML in which this image is in

```
<div class='gf_browser_chrome gform_wrapper' id='gform_wrapper_8' >
  <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='gform_8' action='/etsy-a-deep-dive-into-monitoring-with-skyline/'>
    <div class='gform_heading'>
      <h3 class='gform_title'>Subscribe to our YouTube Channel</h3>
      <span class='gform_description'>Want to get more tech talks? Subscribe to our YouTube channels and get notified when new talks are posted.</span>
    </div>
    <div class='gform_body'>
      <ul id='gform_fields_8' class='gform_fields top_label description_below'>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='gform_footer top_label'>
      <input type='image' src='http://g33ktalk.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/subscribe.gif' id='gform_submit_button_8' class='gform_image_button' alt='Submit' tabindex='1' />
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `margin-left`?

Comment: @dqf13g32g not yet. But I should have :) Trying now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from your CSS: (update the padding values here)

```
.gform_wrapper .gform_footer {
    padding: 16px 0 10px 15px;
    margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    clear: both
}
```

Comment: I know you said you tred to add padding to gform_footer and it had no effect, but this worked for me.  So I am not sure if you were doing it differently initially.

Comment: Just tried it and it still doesn't add the whitespace between the div border and the button :(

Comment: I added more HTML to my original question to give things some context

Comment: It did work for me.  but just in case, please try adding !important to the padding line.

Comment: Actually I have this code in the same css file above: body .gform_wrapper form .gform_body ul li {
 list-style-type:none!important;
 list-style-image:none!important;
 list-style:none!important;
 background-image:none!important;
 background:none!important;
 padding:0 0 8px !important;
 margin:0!important
} - would it overwrite our code? What does it mean when they add the explanation mark next to the margin:0 ?

Comment: Actually, just to confirm: you are making that change in forms.css, right?

Comment: this is in Wordpress and the changes I am making is in style.css

Comment: ok, so that is why you need !important.  style.css loads BEFORE forms.css, so anything you do in style.css will be overridden by styles in forms.css.  Unless you use !important after the style.  .gform_wrapper .gform_footer {padding-left 15px !important;}

Comment: so do you think I should just move my code to forms.css from style.css? And would the ! effect things

Comment: If you can update this class directly in forms.css, then do that.

Answer (score 1):

Usualy when i faced this kind of problem i check my whole css. 
Try to use bootstarp as it they have div's  which will shift your content to the specific locatio on page.
some times we can not say that what we did wrong with CSS so what I usually do is to try to test it with Firebug(firefox) or chrome (DEV tools). or with http://cssdesk.com/ for testing my pages.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to make the selector specific enough to override any subsequent CSS rules that may follow.

I would not use `!important`, instead, I would try something like:

```
div.gform_wrapper .gform_footer {
    padding: 16px 0 10px 0;
    margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    clear: both
}
```